# change OnClick Event imagebutton from code behind

Tags: asp.net, image, onclick, imagebutton

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ib_Add4" OnClick="ib_Add4_Click" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ib_Modify4" OnClick="ib_Modify4_Click" />
```

I want to change OnClick Event about ib_modify4's event  to ib_Add4's OnClick event.

I tried like these.

```
this.ib_Modify4.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(ib_Add4_Click);

this.ib_Modify4.Click += ib_Add4_Click;

this.ib_Modify4.Attributes["OnClick"] = "ib_Add4_Click";
```

but this doesn't work.

how can I set OnClick event in code behind?

Comment: Maybe something like Modify4.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

Comment: @popcorn , what is reason for changing the click event